# Update button on VS works SQL SP, on IIS it just saves the information already there, no update

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, iis-8

I have a web form that shows some header information, you can change that information (text boxes, check box, etc.) and hit the update information button to post the information to a SQL Stored Procedure..

When I run this on Visual Studio and hit the button the information gets updated.

====VISUAL STUDIO====

```
declare @p14 varchar(200)
set @p14=NULL
declare @p15 int
set @p15=NULL
exec DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER_UPDATE @EMP_ID=N'ADA04',@K401_TYPE=N'DECLINED',@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT=NULL,@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT=NULL,@COMPANY_LIFE_EMP=1,@COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE=0,@COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD=1,@COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS=99,@HEALTH_DECLINE=1,@DENTAL_DECLINE=0,@VISION_DECLINE=1,@LIFE_DECLINE=0,@NOTES=N'MY RECORD NEW RECORD INFO',@SP_MESSAGE=@p14 output,@SP_ERROR_NUMBER=@p15 output
select @p14, @p15
go
exec sp_reset_connection 
go
```

When I run the exact same thing in IIS it basically just puts the information back into SQL as if nothing had changed.

=====IIS=====

```
declare @p14 varchar(200)
set @p14=NULL
declare @p15 int
set @p15=NULL
exec DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER_UPDATE @EMP_ID=N'ADA04',@K401_TYPE=N'DECLINED',@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT=NULL,@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT=NULL,@COMPANY_LIFE_EMP=1,@COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE=0,@COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD=1,@COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS=99,@HEALTH_DECLINE=1,@DENTAL_DECLINE=0,@VISION_DECLINE=1,@LIFE_DECLINE=0,@NOTES=N'MY RECORD NEW RECORD INFO',@SP_MESSAGE=@p14 output,@SP_ERROR_NUMBER=@p15 output
select @p14, @p15
```

I changed in the textbox 99 to 4 and MY RECORD NEW RECORD to MY RECORD NEW RECORD INFO WITH NEW NOTES HERE and hit the submit button.

@COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS=99 to 4
and @NOTES to @NOTES=N'MY RECORD NEW RECORD INFO WITH NEW NOTES HERE'

I am not sure what I am missing here.. sorry if it is something pretty basic and I should know better, but I have searched around trying to figure it out.

The SQL connection is SQL username and password not integrated.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeBenefits.aspx.cs" Inherits="DLI_EMPLOYEE_BENEFITS.EmployeeBenefits" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>DLI Employee Benefit Maintenance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 90%;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        html {
            display: table;
            margin: auto;
        }

        body {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 768px;
            margin: 0; /* Space from this element (entire page) and others*/
            padding: 20; /*space from content and border*/
            border: solid blue;
            border-width: thin;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }


        .HeaderLogo {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .PageTitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: x-large;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .LoginName {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .NavBar {
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .DivCenter {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 20%;
            height: 25px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="BODY_DIV">
            <div id="PageTitle" class="PageTitle">
                EMPLOYEE BENEFIT MAINTENANCE<hr />
            </div>
            <div id="EMPLOYEE_BENEFITS_HEADER">
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 15%; font-weight: bold;">EMP ID :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 15%">

                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEMPLOYEE_ID" runat="server" Width="92px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibGET" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/elcmark.png" OnClick="ibGET_Click" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibRESET" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/reset.png" PostBackUrl="https://dlihome.deseretlabs.com/HR/EMP_BENEFITS/EmployeeBenefits.aspx" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 40%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbEMPLOYEE_NAME" runat="server" Text="DOE, JOHN" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 15%; font-weight: bold;">HIRE DATE :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 15%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbHIRE_DATE" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 15%; font-weight: bold;">ENROLL DATE :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 15%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbENROLL_DATE" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>

                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 55%; font-weight: bold;" colspan="2">INITAL MEETING :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 15%">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbINITIAL_MEETING" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibINITIAL_DATE" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/plus16.gif" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr />
                <table class="auto-style1" cellpadding="10px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 20%; font-weight: bold;">401K :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; width: 20%" colspan="4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl401_TYPE" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>DECLINED</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>401K</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>ROTH</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp; &nbsp;♦&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb401_PCT" runat="server" Width="25px" Wrap="False" style="text-align:center"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; PERCENT&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;$
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tb401_AMOUNT" runat="server" Width="64px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;AMOUNT</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 20%; font-weight: bold;">COMPANY LIFE :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; width: 20%" colspan="4">&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbCOMP_LIFE_EMP" runat="server" Text="EMPLOYEE" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbCOMP_LIFE_SPOUSE" runat="server" Text="SPOUSE" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbCOMP_LIFE_CHILDREN" runat="server" Text="CHILDREN" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TbCOMP_LIFE_DEPENDENTS" runat="server" Width="25px" Wrap="False" style="text-align:center"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;DEPENDENTS</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: right; width: 20%; font-weight: bold;">DECLINED BENEFITS :</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; width: 20%" colspan="4">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbDECLINE_HEALTH" runat="server" Text="HEALTH" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbDECLINE_DENTAL" runat="server" Text="DENTAL" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&#9830;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbDECLINE_VISION" runat="server" Text="VISION" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;♦&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="cbDECLINE_LIFE" runat="server" Text="VOLUNTARY LIFE" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: RIGHT; width: 20%; font-weight: bold;">NOTES:</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: LEFT; width: 80%" colspan="4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbNOTES" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: CENTER; width: 100%; font-weight: bold;" colspan="2">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibUPDATE_HEADER" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/button_update-record.png" OnClick="ibUPDATE_HEADER_Click" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSPMessageSuccess" runat="server"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblSPMessageError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
                <hr style="border: 1px solid red;"/>
            </div>
            <div id="ENROLLED_BENEFITS">



                <asp:GridView ID="gvEnrolledBenfits" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="dsEnrolledBenefits" Width="100%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="INS_DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="INS_DESCRIPTION">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="20%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AMOUNT" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="AMOUNT PPC" SortExpression="AMOUNT" >
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LIFE_AMOUNT" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="LIFE AMOUNT" SortExpression="LIFE_AMOUNT" >
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DEPENDENT_CHIDREN" HeaderText="DEPENDENT CHIDREN" SortExpression="DEPENDENT_CHIDREN" >
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="START_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="START DATE" SortExpression="START_DATE" >
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="END_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="END DATE" SortExpression="END_DATE" >
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                </asp:GridView>



                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsEnrolledBenefits" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PAYROLL %>" SelectCommand="DLI_BENEFITS_EMPLOYEE_ENROLLED" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbEMPLOYEE_ID" Name="EID" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>



            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;


    namespace DLI_EMPLOYEE_BENEFITS
    {
        public partial class EmployeeBenefits : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //if (!IsPostBack)

                //{

                //    lbEMPLOYEE_NAME.Text = "";
                //    tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text = "";
                //}


                ibINITIAL_DATE.Visible = false;
                lblSPMessageSuccess.Text = "";

                string qsEmpID = Request.QueryString["qsEmpID"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(qsEmpID))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text = qsEmpID.ToUpper();
                    MyLookup();

                }
            }

            protected void ibGET_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
            {
                MyLookup();
            }

            private void MyLookup()
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text))
                {
                    lbEMPLOYEE_NAME.Text = "INVALID EMPLOYEE ID";
                }
                else
                {
                    lbEMPLOYEE_NAME.Text = tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text.ToUpper();
                    tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text = tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text.ToUpper();

                    int EmpID = -1;

                    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PAYROLL"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DLI_BENEFITS_EMP_ID_VALIDATE"))
                        {

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text.ToUpper());
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    if (EmpID != -1)
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER"))
                            {

                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text.ToUpper());
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                                while (dataReader.Read())
                                {

                                    lbEMPLOYEE_NAME.Text = dataReader["EMPLOYEE_NAME"].ToString();
                                    ddl401_TYPE.SelectedValue = dataReader["401K_TYPE"].ToString();
                                    tb401_PCT.Text = dataReader["CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT"].ToString();
                                    tb401_AMOUNT.Text = dataReader["CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT"].ToString();
                                    cbCOMP_LIFE_EMP.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["COMPANY_LIFE_EMP"]);
                                    cbCOMP_LIFE_SPOUSE.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE"]);
                                    cbCOMP_LIFE_CHILDREN.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD"]);
                                    TbCOMP_LIFE_DEPENDENTS.Text = dataReader["COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS"].ToString();
                                    cbDECLINE_HEALTH.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["HEALTH_DECLINE"]);
                                    cbDECLINE_DENTAL.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["DENTAL_DECLINE"]);
                                    cbDECLINE_VISION.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["VISION_DECLINE"]);
                                    cbDECLINE_LIFE.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataReader["LIFE_DECLINE"]);
                                    tbNOTES.Text = dataReader["NOTES"].ToString();
                                    lbENROLL_DATE.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["ENROLL"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                    lbHIRE_DATE.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["HIRE_DATE"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                    lbINITIAL_MEETING.Text = "";
                                    ibINITIAL_DATE.Visible = true;
                                    if (dataReader["INIT_MEETING"].GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                                    {
                                        lbINITIAL_MEETING.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["INIT_MEETING"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                        ibINITIAL_DATE.Visible = false;
                                    }




                                }
                                con.Close();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        lbEMPLOYEE_NAME.Text = tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text.ToUpper() + " is not valid.";
                    }


                }
            }

            protected void ibUPDATE_HEADER_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
            {
                string @EMP_ID = Convert.ToString(tbEMPLOYEE_ID.Text).ToUpper();
                string @K401_TYPE = Convert.ToString(ddl401_TYPE.SelectedValue).ToUpper();
                string @NOTES = Convert.ToString(tbNOTES.Text).ToUpper();

                string cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PAYROLL"].ConnectionString;

                //Response.Write(cnString);

                lblSPMessageSuccess.Text = "";

                SqlConnection cn = null;
                try
                {
                    cn = new SqlConnection(cnString);
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER_UPDATE", cn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_ID", @EMP_ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@K401_TYPE", @K401_TYPE.ToString());

                    if (decimal.TryParse(tb401_AMOUNT.Text, out decimal parsed))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT", decimal.Parse(tb401_AMOUNT.Text));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT", DBNull.Value);
                    }

                    if (Int16.TryParse(tb401_PCT.Text, out Int16 parsed1))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT", Int16.Parse(tb401_PCT.Text));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT", DBNull.Value);
                    }


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_LIFE_EMP", cbCOMP_LIFE_EMP.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE", cbCOMP_LIFE_SPOUSE.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD", cbCOMP_LIFE_CHILDREN.Checked);

                    if (Int16.TryParse(TbCOMP_LIFE_DEPENDENTS.Text, out Int16 parsed2))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS", Int16.Parse(TbCOMP_LIFE_DEPENDENTS.Text));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS", DBNull.Value);
                    }

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HEALTH_DECLINE", cbDECLINE_HEALTH.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DENTAL_DECLINE", cbDECLINE_DENTAL.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VISION_DECLINE", cbDECLINE_VISION.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIFE_DECLINE", cbDECLINE_LIFE.Checked);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTES", @NOTES.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SP_MESSAGE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SP_ERROR_NUMBER", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    int output = (int)cmd.Parameters["@SP_ERROR_NUMBER"].Value;
                    string output_message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@SP_MESSAGE"].Value;

                    if (output == -1)
                    {
                        lblSPMessageSuccess.Text = "";
                        lblSPMessageError.Text = output_message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblSPMessageError.Text = "";
                        lblSPMessageSuccess.Text = output_message;


                        //dsEnrolledBenefits.EnableCaching = false;
                        //dsEnrolledBenefits.EnableCaching = true;
                        //this.dsEnrolledBenefits.DataBind();
                        //this.gvOpenProjects.DataBind();

                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblSPMessageError.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn != null)
                    {
                        cn.Close();
                        MyLookup();
                    }
                }











            }
        }
    }
```

```sql
USE [PAYDEMO]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER_UPDATE]    Script Date: 7/23/2019 8:46:39 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO







CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DLI_BENEFITS_HEADER_UPDATE]
      @EMP_ID [varchar](15),
      @K401_TYPE [nvarchar](10),
      @CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT [decimal](12, 2),
      @CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT [tinyint],
      @COMPANY_LIFE_EMP [bit],
      @COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE [bit],
      @COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD [bit],
      @COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS [tinyint],
      @HEALTH_DECLINE [bit],
      @DENTAL_DECLINE [bit],
      @VISION_DECLINE [bit],
      @LIFE_DECLINE [bit],
      @NOTES [nvarchar](max),
      @SP_MESSAGE varchar(200) OUTPUT,
      @SP_ERROR_NUMBER int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

SET @SP_ERROR_NUMBER = 0




IF @SP_ERROR_NUMBER = 0
BEGIN

UPDATE       EMPLOYEE_PTO_401k
SET                [401K_TYPE] = @K401_TYPE, CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT = @CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_AMOUNT, CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT = @CONTRIBUTION_RATE_401K_PCT, COMPANY_LIFE_EMP = @COMPANY_LIFE_EMP, 
                         COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE = @COMPANY_LIFE_SPOUSE, COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD = @COMPANY_LIFE_CHILD, COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS = @COMPANY_LIFE_DEPENDENTS, HEALTH_DECLINE = @HEALTH_DECLINE, DENTAL_DECLINE = @DENTAL_DECLINE, 
                         VISION_DECLINE = @VISION_DECLINE, LIFE_DECLINE = @LIFE_DECLINE, NOTES = @NOTES
WHERE        (EMP_ID = @EMP_ID)

SELECT @SP_MESSAGE = 'RECORD UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY',  @SP_ERROR_NUMBER = 0
END

END
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I the config file the same for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoridng to your description and codes, I found you call the MyLookup in the page load method. If the query string qsEmpID has the value. It will call the MyLookup method again.

If you call button click event, it will re-binding the server control if the query string has the value before calling the update method. I suggest you could re-desgin your page load method.

Comment: I had to move it to not post back and it solved the issue.  Thanks.